# Drawing spiral square with python opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to draw a spiral square in python using OpenCV and Numpy.
I know that I can do it via turtle and there are so many examples on the internet but I need to do it as I described in the title.
So I drew chessboard [chessboard via python OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K71QO.png)

This is code for it

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

mySize = 256
myOffset = 16
mySquare = 32
myNumberY = mySize // mySquare
myNumberX = mySize // mySquare
myColor = 255
img = np.ones((mySize + 2 * myOffset, mySize + 2 * myOffset), dtype = np.uint8) * 127

for y in range(myNumberY) :
    for x in range(myNumberX) :
        myColor = 0 if (x + y) % 2 == 0 else 255
        print(y, x, myColor)
        for ix in range(mySquare) :
            for iy in range(mySquare) :
                img[myOffset + y * mySquare + iy][myOffset + x * mySquare + ix] = myColor
cv2.imshow('my image', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Next, I have some kind of squares - one inside the other.

[image: Squares one inside other]

And this is code for it.

```
import cv2, numpy

mySize, myOffset, mySquare, myColor = 256, 16, 16, 0

img = numpy.ones((mySize + 2 * myOffset, mySize + 2 * myOffset), dtype = numpy.uint8) * 127

for item in range(mySize // mySquare // 2) :
    myTempOffsetStart = myOffset + item * mySquare
    myTempOffsetFinish = myOffset + mySize - item * mySquare
    myColor = 0 if myColor == 255 else 255
    img[myTempOffsetStart : myTempOffsetFinish, myTempOffsetStart : myTempOffsetFinish] = myColor

cv2.imshow('my image', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can change the size of drawing pictures (lines) by changing `mySquare` value.

So for me important is to draw square spirals like this in the following picture.

[image: Spiral square - example]

Comment: well, emulate a "turtle": keep a pen position, do your turtle code with rotation and movement, and draw lines accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the picture you see that the pattern is actually pretty simple. You have to go `right, up, left, down` and repeat a few times. Also the distance you have to go starts with 3 and goes up by two every other step.

After having down that I calculate how much space I need to draw that and shift the points so the coordinates are not negative. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import numpy as np

repeates = 10
directions = [(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)]

moves = [(3+2*(i//2))*np.array(d) 
         for i,d in enumerate(itertools.chain(*itertools.repeat(directions, repeates)))]
points = (np.array([0,0]),*itertools.accumulate(moves))

coordinates = np.array(points).reshape(-1)
r1,r2 = coordinates.min(), coordinates.max()
n = r2-r1+1
img = np.zeros((n,n))

for p,q in zip(points[0:-1],points[1:]):
    cv2.line(img, tuple(p-r1), tuple(q-r1), (1,1,1))

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

And it looks like this

[image: square spiral]